# Herkunft und Verwendung des Wortes „deren“

Tags: pronoun, genitive, inflection

Ich versuche meine Frage auf Deutsch zu stellen, weil ich Deutsch lerne.

Meine Frage ist über das Wort *deren*. Ich habe einen Satz gelesen, der wie folgt lautet:

> Alle, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist, kommen entweder aus
>   Deutschland, Österreich, der Schweiz, Liechtenstein oder Luxemburg.

Ich bin wirklich verwirrt, woher das Wort *deren* kommt? Ich hab es erstmals gelesen. Ist das ein Genitiv? Gibt es kein anderes Wort, das es ersetzen kann oder an dessen Stelle *deren* verwendet werden kann? Wie ist das Wort *deren* im Genitiv formal abgeleitet?

Comment: [Flexion von *die* auf canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/inflection/die:Pron:Relative:PL)

Comment: Der Satz ist inhaltlich natürlich nicht ganz richtig. Unter anderem deshalb, weil es z.B. auch in Brasilien und in den USA deutschsprachige Minderheiten gibt.

Comment: PS: Und natürlich auch in Dänemark, Belgien, Frankreich, Italien, Rumänien und einigen ehemaligen Ländern der Sowjetunion.

Comment: Hallo @Jan , viele viele Dank . Ich bin wirklich dankbar, dass Sie für die Korrektur meiner falschen Sätzen. Das ist außerordentlich hilfreich.

Comment: Hallo @HansAdler , Sie sind richtig. Ich habe Ich hatte gerade den Satz erstellt, um nur ein Beispiel zu nennen. Vielen Dank.

Comment: @SyParth Unter Benutzern im Internet ist es in der Regel üblich, einander mit *du* anzusprechen ;) Ein *Sie* wirkt überzogen-distanziert. Aber hast du nun *gesagt* oder *gehört/gelesen*?

Comment: @Jan ich hab es gelesen :) .

Comment: @SyParth Alles klar, dann steht das jetzt so in der Frage ;)

Comment: @Jan Das sehe ich aber ganz anders. Im Gegenteil kommt es meiner Meinung nach sehr darauf an, in welcher Community man sich im Internet bewegt. Hier beispielsweise ist es OK, die Leute zu duzen. In anderen Foren würde ich das nicht tun. SyParth ist nicht übertrieben distanziert, lediglich höflich.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's genitiv of "die" (singluar and plural). So you might say:

```
Alle, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist, ...
Jack, dessen Muttersprache Deutsch ist, ...
Alice, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist, ...
```

See also [here](https://www.dietz-und-daf.de/GD_DkfA/Gramminfo/txt_MI2/Relsatz%20deren&dessen%20lg.pdf), [here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deren_Demonstrativpronomen), or [here](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-der-die-das.html).

There is no alternative for it with your current sentence structure.

Comment: Thank you very much, My knowledge about this genitive form was very little,

Answer (score 3):

„Deren“ ist der Genitiv des [deutschen Relativpronomens](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen#Deutsche_Sprache) im Plural (in Deinem Beispiel) und auch im Singular feminin.

Comment: Vielen Dank , ich freue mich uber Ihren Antworten. Das is sehr hilfreich.